# How to choose best value of 2 discrete parameters simultaneously?

Tags: experiment-design, optimization, nonparametric

I have devised an algorithm that takes as input a dataset $s$ and two parameters, $k$ and $d$. $k$ is discrete while $d$ is categorical. My algorithm outputs a vector $v$ of length 20 which contains real numbers between 0 an 1.

I run my algorithm on three different datasets $s_1$, $s_2$, $s_3$. For each dataset, I vary $k$ in the range {5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60}, and I vary $d$ from {1, 2, 3}. I run each combination and save the resulting $v$.

My goal is to find out which values of $k$ and $d$ show the best average performance (in terms of $v$, larger values are better) across all three datasets. I'm ideally looking for a test or method that will tell me exactly which value of $k$ and $d$ are the best overall values for these three datasets.

How can I do this?

Comment: You seem to be saying "I have this procedure that inputs a $k$ and a $d$ and outputs a number (the mean of $\mathbf{v}$).  How can I maximize the output?"  This question is so generic that it is not answerable.  You can obtain useful answers by providing information about the mathematical behavior of this process.

Comment: If it were just a matter of optimizing $k$ and $d$ for the mean of $v$ for _one_ dataset, the answer would be easy: simply take the $k$ and $d$ that produce the largest value mean($v$). What makes this problem tricky is that I have _multiple_ datasets. For example, $k$=40 and $d$=1 may produce the best answer for $s_1$, but $k$=30 and $d$=2 may produce the best answer for $s_2$. The particular values I'm looking for may not produce the best answer in any individual dataset, but instead produces the best compromise between the three.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm can be conceptualised as a map $\mathcal{A}: S \times \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N} \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{20}$ which we can write in familiar notation as $\vec{v}(S; d,k) = \mathcal{A}(S; d,k)$.

Your problem can be formally stated in at least of a couple of ways: single-objective optimization or multi-objective optimization.

#### Single-Objective Optimization

In this formulation of the problem you must pick some scalar function to assess how 'good' a vector is, which is to say your loss function $\mathcal{L}:\mathbb{R}^{20}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$. One simple example is to sum the components of the vector (achieved below by taking the dot product of $\vec{V}$ with a row vector of ones $\vec{1} = [\underbrace{1, \cdots, 1}_{20}]$)

$$(d^*, k^*) = \arg\max_{d,k} \mathbb{E}_{S} \left[ \vec{1} \cdot \vec{v}(S; d,k) \right]$$

which you wish to estimate with

$$(d^*, k^*) \approx \arg\max_{d,k} \frac{1}{3} \sum_{i=1}^{3} \vec{1} \cdot \vec{v}(s_i; d,k)$$

where $d \in \{1,2,3\}$ rather than $d \in \mathbb{N}$ and $k \in \{5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60\}$ rather than $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

#### Multi-Objective Optimization

Alternatively to the single-objective case where you would aggregate the vectors by some function, such as summation of the components. But perhaps you think that each of the 20 components of $\vec{v}(S; d,k)$ should be considered an objective in their own right. This opens up a wonderful, but complicated, area of optimization called "multiobjective optimization" (MO).

For this I (almost unilaterally) recommend [Emmerich & Deutz 2018](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11047-018-9685-y) on this subject because:

1. They give the required mathematical background (e.g. Pareto orders and Pareto fronts) to MO at an undergraduate level (i.e. it is relatively accessible)
2. Surveys a few long-standing techniques (e.g. Chebyshev scalarization)
3. Introduce the use of evolutionary algorithms for MO (which for your case can include discrete parameters)

> Footnote: I agree with @whuber's comment that explaining the algorithm would likely yield answers more useful to your specific use case. After looking at [your history](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/6979/stepthom) I've surmised that your question was answered in a [follow-up post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22188/how-to-determine-the-combination-of-factor-levels-for-which-the-response-variabl).